# How to run this Excel macro without having to click 'Yes' on the dialog each time?

Tags: vba, excel

I have written the following macro in Excel which changes the file type from .xls to .xlsx, however it asks for confirmation to save in a format without macros. I have to click yes on each file I convert and I have to convert thousands of files. Does anyone know how I get the box to stop popping up i.e. save without macros enabled by default?

```
Sub ConvertToXlsx()
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    ' Path must end in trailing backslash
    strPath = "C:\Excel\"
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls")
    Do While strFile <> ""
        If Right(strFile, 3) = "xls" Then
            Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath & strFile)
            wbk.SaveAs Filename:=strPath & strFile & "x", _
                FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
            wbk.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If
        strFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't add the extension to the filename. It has nothing to do with the saved version. The `FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook` parameter will add the correct .xlsx file extension.
2. Use `application.displayalerts = false` before the save. Be sure to use`application.displayalerts = true` before exiting the sub.

Comment: Can you tell me where exactly I add the application.displayalerts = true and application.displayalerts = falsee ? i.e. tabbed, not tabbed - what line do they go before?

Comment: put `application.displayalerts = false` anywhere before `Do While strFile <> ""`. put `application.displayalerts = true` somewhere after the loop. Note that I originally had them reversed. Fixed above.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you, that worked. One note though, I had to keep the extension "x" at the end of the save line, otherwise it tried to save it as a .xls and I get an error. Don't know why

Comment: No, you should remove the .xls.